# What are steps to compile code on windows?

Tags: c++-actor-framework

I am looking for instructions for compiling the framework on windows. Can somebody post a reply with detailed steps?

Running configure script does not help.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried and had a problem building `master` on Windows.  Here's what I did to build on Windows using VS17.

1. Start a Visual Studio command prompt
2. `cd actor-framework`
3. `git checkout 0.16.1`
4. `mkdir build`
5. `cd build`
6. `cmake .. -DCAF_NO_PYTHON=yes -DCAF_NO_OPENCL=yes -DCAF_NO_TOOLS=yes 
             -DCAF_NO_EXAMPLES=yes -DCAF_NO_UNIT_TESTS=yes -DCAF_LOG_LEVEL=1`
7. `cmake --build .`

Alternatively you can use `caf/0.16.1@bincrafters/stable` in [Conan Center](https://bintray.com/bincrafters/public-conan/caf%3Abincrafters/0.16.1%3Astable).